# How to custom excerpt?

Tags: excerpt

I wanted to make the excerpt only display second or third paragraph.

I need to know. How can I make the_excerpt() only display second or third paragraph and limit the length of the except.

Comment: Want to add custom limit to your content ?

Comment: What if there are other things in the post? Images, tables, and so on? How is the "second paragraph" defined exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the content of excerpt by dot.
For example:

```
$text = "Morbi consequat tempor augue. Nec fringilla eros auctor scelerisque. Etiam in ullamcorper tellus. Sed ac dui rutrum.";
$pieces = explode(".", $text);
echo $pieces[1]; // get second sentence = Nec fringilla eros auctor scelerisque
```

Maybe this can help you.

Comment: Why do you get second sentence? The question is about paragraphs, not sentences. Also... Your code doesn't change output of `the_excerpt()` function, but explodes some constant string...